# Swift: Xcode 6.1.1 change views triggered by code block executions rather than buttons

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6, uistoryboardsegue, xcode-storyboard

I am working on an iOS app that works with a bluetooth device. I have a `.swift` file with callback functions and each callback function changes my variable *state*. Every time *state* changes, I want the views to change. I've attempted `.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`, `sourceViewController.presentViewController(destinationViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)`, and performing a segue. When I google, I only find solutions using `UIButtons` with `@IBAction` functions.

If anyone knows how to change views triggered by code block executions rather than buttons, I would appreciate any thoughts. Below is my code for callbacks and commented where and what triggers the scene to switch.

```
enum State: String {
case Inactive = "Inactive"
case Searching = "Searching"
case CheckingOut = "CheckingOut"
case InRental = "InRental"
case Returned = "Returned"
}   

class RentalController: UIViewController, bleDelegate {
var state = State.Inactive
var unlocked: Bool = false
var service = btDiscoverySharedInstance.bleService

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func startBLE() {
    btDiscoverySharedInstance
    btDiscoverySharedInstance.Bdelegate = self

    service?.startDiscoveringServices()

    state = State.Searching // Start at Home Screen
    println(state.rawValue)

}

func devicefound() {

    service?.fireSolenoid()

    state = State.CheckingOut // Change to Screen 1
    unlocked = true
    println(state.rawValue)
    segment.perform()
}

func btnNotification(value: NSData){

    let pBuffer: [Byte] = [0x00]
    let rBuffer: [Byte] = [0x02]
    let buttonPressed = NSData(bytes: pBuffer, length: pBuffer.count)
    let buttonReleased = NSData(bytes: rBuffer, length: rBuffer.count)

    if(value == buttonPressed) {

        state = State.InRental  // Change to Screen 2
        println(state.rawValue)
        //viewDidAppear(false)
    }

    // Disconnect then reconnect
    if(value == buttonReleased) {

        state = State.Returned // Change back to home screen
        println(state.rawValue)
        btDiscoverySharedInstance.disconnect()

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First select the segue that you'd like to navigate to. In the attribut inspector define some identifier.

In your class call this method:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Identifier", sender: self)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but doing so throws me this error that I don't understand.  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<UserApp.RentalController: 0x165748e0>) has no segue with identifier 'centerToNav''. Any ideas? I feel like no matter which class I put the method in, it responds with a similar error.

Comment: Hmm, well you haven't set the identifier correctly then. You have to click on the segue itself to set the identifier, have you done this?

Comment: Yes I did. I've also tried a prepareForSegue function but I was running into trouble there as well. Do you know if there is any other preparation function I'd need for the class to recognize an existing segue?